# If $\frak{g}$ = $span\lbrace{e_{1},e_{2}}\rbrace$ is a Lie algebra such that $[e_{1},e_{2}] = e_{1}$, show that $Der(\frak{g})$ = $ad(\frak{g})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $\frak{g}$ = $span\lbrace{e_{1},e_{2}}\rbrace$ is a Lie algebra such that 
$[e_{1},e_{2}] = e_{1}$, show that $Der(\frak{g})$ = $ad(\frak{g})$.

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: You have the explicit bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$; just write out $\operatorname{Der}$ and $\operatorname{ad}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is linear algebra. We can write $D(e_i)=a_{i1}e_1+a_{i2}e_2$ for $i=1,2$, since $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis. Then, by definition of a derivation
$$
D([e_i,e_j])=[D(e_i),e_j]+[e_i,D(e_j)]=[a_{i1}e_1+a_{i2}e_2,e_j]+[e_i,a_{j1}e_1+a_{j2}e_2]
$$
Expand this to the basis and compare coefficients. We may assume that $i=1$ and $j=2$. Then the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was an excellent suggestion.